# what operations is there to crop a raster to the extent of another raster?

Tags: r, raster, crop, extent

I have 3 rasters that I have to multiply for reclassifcation before I reclassify again, but before I do the multiplication I must make 3 rasters same extent. There is a difference in xmax for distance raster

```
ext(dem)
ext(slope)
ext(distance)

ext(dem)
SpatExtent : 1089831.75, 1721631.75, 4748091, 5516991 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
ext(slope)
SpatExtent : 1089831.75, 1721631.75, 4748091, 5516991 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
ext(distance)
SpatExtent : 1089831.75, 1721031.75, 4748091, 5516991 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

I have tried follwing answers on other questions but am still failing, I have tried the follwoing with cropping to the extent of slope and dem for distance

```
distance <- crop(slope, distance)
distance <- crop(dem, distance)
```

but after runnig it and checking the ext again it still doesn't fix it. I have checked projections and they are all the same too.

Comment: you can simply set the extent of any raster with `raster::extent()` . it should lok something like this `raster::extent(slope) <- c(xmin=1089831.75, xmax=1721031.75, ymin=4748091, ymax=5516991)`

Answer (score 1):

You do not `show(dem)` and `show(distance)` making it very difficult to give a specific answer. All we can see is that the x extent of `distance` is 600 (m) less than that of the other rasters. In the future please provide a reproducible example by creating the SpatRasters in code (see `as.character(dem)` to get started), like this

```
 library(terra)
 dem <- rast(ncol=, nrow=, xmin=, ....)
```

`crop` can only remove *whole* rows and columns (you cannot have a fraction of a raster cell). I suspect that the extent you expect does not meet that requirement. But it may get you closer. If it is very close (that is, the difference is much less than the spatial resolution, and the number of rows and columns match), you could do

```
ext(distance) <- ext(slope)
```

Otherwise, consider `resample`

```
distance2 <- resample(distance, slope)
```